# ¿Como ocultar un elemento por ejemplo un formulario en html pero que siga funcionando?

Tags: html

estoy trabajando en un proyecto y realizo una conexión a un formulario en una página web, pero no quiero que el formulario se vea (estar oculto a la vista) pero aun así siga teniendo la funcionalidad, para que mi software lo siga usando (cliente)

Comment: Sé un poco más descriptivo, cuéntanos la idea de tener el formulario oculto y en qué momento se deberá mostrar u ocultar.

Comment: En teoría solo sería añadirle un CSS al formulario <form ... style="display: none">...</form>

Comment: Hola, quizá deberías empezar completando el [tour] para comprender cómo se espera que las preguntas sean planteadas, explicando con detalle tu problema y aportando un [mcve]. Bienvenido a SOes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazlo de esta manera:

```
<form id="DataForm" style="display:none" action="..." method = "POST">

</form>
```

De esta manera podrás tener un formulario oculto, pero podrás hacer submit mediante su ID desde javascript. Suerte.

Comment: si, gracias ya lo hice funcionar con el style="display:none".

Answer (score 0):

Usa el tipo hidden: `<input type="hidden">`